# My Android service is not running all the time. it goes off when i reopen the app. what is the correct way of implementing my service?

Tags: android, android-service

i have developed a android application, in which i have integrated broadcast receiver with android service. my motto is whenever device is connected to internet it will perform some action. it is working fine for the very first time when i install the app. but when i reopen my app it is not working. where should i declare my service so that it will run irrespective of app opens or closes or reopens! whatever happens it should run in bg always and perform some action(as i programmed to do) when internet is connected. How can i do that? Below is my android service code

```
package processteam.ju;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class AndroidService extends Service {
    Timer t;
    Timer t1;
    TimerTask task;
    TimerTask task1;
    int time = 20;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startService(new Intent(this, AndroidService.class));
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
public void zipper(){
    {
        File uploadedimagedirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Uploaded_Images/");
        File[] imagecontents = uploadedimagedirectory.listFiles();

        if (imagecontents == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploadedimagedirectory null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (imagecontents.length == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploadedimagedirectory empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploadedimagedirectory 1st line", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                String inputFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Uploaded_Images/";
                String outZipPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Images_Media_Zip/images.zip";

                Toast.makeText(this, "uploadimg2dp try block" + inputFolderPath + " ---" + outZipPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outZipPath);
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

                Toast.makeText(this, "What i get in uploadimg2dp" + inputFolderPath + "  <-->  " + outZipPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                File srcFile = new File(inputFolderPath);
                File[] files = srcFile.listFiles();

                Toast.makeText(this, "S.no " + srcFile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
                    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    zos.closeEntry();
                    fis.close();
                }
                zos.close();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e("", ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }

        File uploadedvideodirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Uploaded_Videos/");
        File[] videocontents = uploadedvideodirectory.listFiles();

        if (videocontents == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploadedvideodirectory null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (videocontents.length == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploadedvideodirectory empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploadedvideodirectory executed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            try {
                String inputFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Uploaded_Videos";
                String outZipPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Videos_Media_Zip/videos.zip";

                Toast.makeText(this, "exv" + inputFolderPath + " ---" + outZipPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outZipPath);

                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
                Toast.makeText(this, "What i get in zip2 " + inputFolderPath + "  <-->  " + outZipPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                File srcFile = new File(inputFolderPath);

                File[] files = srcFile.listFiles();

                Log.d("", "Zip directory: " + srcFile.getName());

                Toast.makeText(this, "S.no " + srcFile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    Log.d("", "Adding file: " + files[i].getName());
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
                    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
                    int length;
                    Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586ly");
                    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    zos.closeEntry();
                    fis.close();
                    Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586hy");
                }
                zos.close();
                Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586yt");

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e("", ioe.getMessage());
            }


        }
        Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586w");
        uploadmedia2dp();
        Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586y");

    }
}

public void startTimer() {

    Log.d("Download123456", "Starts123456");

    t = new Timer();

    task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            DBUploaderDownloader mydb = new DBUploaderDownloader(getApplicationContext(), 0);

            //mydb.execute("1");
        }
    };
    SimpleDateFormat currenthour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
    SimpleDateFormat currentime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(currenthour.format(cal.getTime()));
    String target = currentdate.format(new Date());

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i = i + 1) {
        if (hours == i) {
            String ss = String.valueOf(i);
            if (i < 10) {
                ss = "0" + ss;
            }
            target = target + " " + ss + ":30:00";
            break;
        }
    }

    String currentdttime = currentime.format(new Date());
    Date targetedtime = null;
    try {
        targetedtime = currentime.parse(target);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long diff = targetedtime.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();

    //t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 100, 20000);
    //t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, diff, 3600000);
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 100, 1800000);
}
public void downloaddb() {


}
public void startUploadTimer() {

    Log.d("Upload123456", "Starts123456");
    t1 = new Timer();

    task1 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

          /*  DBUploaderDownloader mydb = new DBUploaderDownloader(getApplicationContext(), 0);
            mydb.execute("2");*/


            downloaddb();
        }


    };
    SimpleDateFormat currenthour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
    SimpleDateFormat currentime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(currenthour.format(cal.getTime()));
    String target = currentdate.format(new Date());

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i = i + 1) {
        if (hours == i) {
            String ss = String.valueOf(i);
            if (i < 10) {
                ss = "0" + ss;
            }
            target = target + " " + ss + ":00:00";
            break;
        }
    }

    String currentdttime = currentime.format(new Date());
    Date targetedtime = null;
    try {
        targetedtime = currentime.parse(target);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long diff = targetedtime.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
    Log.d("1234","diff="+String.valueOf(diff));
    //t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 100, 360000);
    //t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, diff, 3600000);
    //t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 100, 1800000);
    t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 100, 1200000);
}
public void uploadmedia2dp(){

    Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586");
    /*Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DropBoxActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);*/

    Intent in=new Intent().setClass(AndroidService.this,DropBoxActivity.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(in);
   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"uploadmedia2dp executed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("ranjithkpr","814858058678");
}
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
                if (t != null) {
                    t.cancel();
                }

                if (t1 != null) {
                    t1.cancel();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //startTimer();
                //startUploadTimer();
                //uploadvideo2dp();
                //uploadmedia2dp();

                //uploadimage2dp();

                zipper();

                RecursiveFileObserver recursiveFileObserver = new RecursiveFileObserver(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Uploaded_Videos/");
                recursiveFileObserver.startWatching();
                Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586ggy");

                RecursiveFileObserver recursiveFileObserver2 = new RecursiveFileObserver(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/JU_Mobile_Files/Uploaded_Images/");
                recursiveFileObserver2.startWatching();
                Log.d("ranjithkpr","8148580586yre");





            } else {
                if (t != null) {
                    t.cancel();
                }
                if (t1 != null) {
                    t1.cancel();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DisConnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
};
```

}

and i'm starting my service from mainactivity(in oncreate) like this,

```
 if (settings.getBoolean("createuploaderdownloadtimer11", true)) {

            startService(new Intent(this, AndroidService.class));
            settings.edit().putBoolean("createuploaderdownloadtimer11", false).commit();
        }
```

and this is how i have declared in manifest,

```
 <service android:name=".AndroidService" >
        </service>
```

When i close my from recent apps options, my service also closing!

it should perform the action when net is connected, but is not!

What should i do? Any help?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you should learn about wake locks and foreground services

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713247/android-service-stop-when-application-is-reopened-and-closed link So that you can get the exact idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this:

```
settings.edit().putBoolean("createuploaderdownloadtimer11", false).commit();
```

before startService call like this:

```
settings.edit().putBoolean("createuploaderdownloadtimer11", false).commit();
startService(new Intent(this, AndroidService.class));
```

Comment: wow! @Green goblin! one single line changing helped me! thank you so much! it is working all the time now! :) Thank You gobin!

Comment: Accept this as answer :)